# My first program

Tags: python, if-statement, calculator

I've been doing a lot lessons on Code Academy, but I get frustrated since some of the compilers reject answers that return the same results. So, I decided to breakaway for a bit and create my own program with the tools that I have learned which is a calculator. It doesn't run correctly. When it is at the menu the if/elif/else statements do not work. The program seems to ignore the input . So, here is my first program code...

```
import math
user_choice=(">>")
def add():
    print "What two numbers would you like to add?"
    a= int(raw_input(user_choice))                     
    b= int(raw_input(user_choice))
    c= a + b
    print c
def sub():
    print "What two numbers would you like to subtract?"
    a=int(raw_input(user_choice))
    b=int(raw_input(user_choice))
    c=a-b
    print c
def mult():
    print "What two numbers would you like to multiply?"
    a=int(raw_input(user_choice))
    b=int(raw_input(user_choice))
    c= a*b
    print c
def div():
    print "What two numbers would you like to divide?"
    a=int(raw_input(user_choice))
    b=int(raw_input(user_choice))
    c=a/b
    print c
def exp():
    print "What number would you like to power?"
    a=int(raw_input(user_choice))
    print "By what number would you like it to be powered to?"
    b=int(raw_input(user_choice))
    c= math.pow(a,b)
    print  c
def square():
    print "What number would you like to square root?"
    a=int(raw_input(user_choice))
    b=math.sqrt(a)
    print b

print "+---------------------------+"   
print "|   Welcome to my basic     |"
print "|    calculator!         |"
print "|                           |"
print "|What would you like to do? |"
print "|                |"
print "|1: Addition         |"
print "|2: Subtraction          |"
print "|3: Multiplication       |"
print "|4: Division         |"
print "|5: Exponents            |"
print "|6: Square Root          |"
print "|7: Quit         |"
print "|                           |"
print "+---------------------------+"

if int(raw_input(user_choice)) ==  "1":
     add()

elif int(raw_input(user_choice)) == "2":
     sub()

elif int(raw_input(user_choice)) == "3":
     mult()

elif int(raw_input(user_choice)) == "4":
     div()

elif int(raw_input(user_choice)) == "5":
     exp()

elif int(raw_input(user_choice)) == "6":
     square()

elif int(raw_input(user_choice)) == "7":
     exit()

else:
    print "Sorry, I didn't understand your entry.Try entering a value 1-7"
```

there is no "if error" code yet, but I am just adamant about getting it to work. All of the functions work. Just can't get the options to work.

Comment: You should request the user input _before_ you check it... you're requesting the user input every time a condition is checked in your main code. Also, strings != ints.

Comment: `if int(raw_input(user_choice)) ==  "1":` as you're converting the input to `int`, you shall compare it directly with `int`

Comment: Once you fix the problem pointed out below by Paul, you may want to send this code to codereview.stackexchange.com and get some advice on how you can minimize the amount of conditionals you have and allow more features

Answer (score 4):

`int(rawinput())` will return an `integer`, which will not be `==` to a string like `"1"`.  Remove the `int()` from them and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if int(raw_input(user_choice)) ==  "1":
```

To

```
if int(raw_input(user_choice)) ==  1:
```

Number should not be quoted, only literal string should.
A suggestion, you can get the input just once, and then do the if/elif/else conditional test, for example:

```
option = int(raw_input(user_choice))
print "You choose %d" % option

if option == 1:
    add()
elif option == 2:
    sub()
......
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the things others have pointed out, I will leave here how I personally would implement it. This surely isn't the best way, but I hope it might give you some idea (which you either will adopt or reject) and some points where you can investigate further in order to broaden your python skills:

```
class Operation:
    def __init__(self, f, argc):
        #f is the function to use, argc the number of arguments it takes
        self.f = f
        self.argc = argc

    def __call__(self):
        #read in the args
        args = [int(input('>> ')) for _ in range (self.argc)]
        #print out the result of the function passed in the ctor
        print(self.f(*args))

#your operations keyed to the options of your menu
operations = {'1': Operation(lambda a, b: a + b, 2),
              '2': Operation(lambda a, b: a - b, 2),
              '3': Operation(lambda a, b: a * b, 2),
              '4': Operation(lambda a, b: a / b, 2),
              '5': Operation(lambda a, b: a ** b, 2),
              '6': Operation(lambda a: a ** .5, 1)}

while True:
    print('''
1: Addition
2: Subtraction
3: Multiplication
4: Division
5: Exponentiation
6: Square root
7: Quit''')
    choice = input('Your choice: ') #raw_input for py2
    if choice == '7': break
    try: operations[choice]()
    #KeyError means choice is not in the dict
    except KeyError: print('Unkown option')
    #Something else went wrong, division by zero, etc
    except Exception as e: print('Something went horribly wrong: {}'.format(e))
```